# What will happen passing sizeof

Tags: c++, sizeof

I have this problem I don't understand why I get the incorrect result:

```
    if(sizeof(int) > -1)
        cout << "true" << endl;
    else
        cout << "false" << endl;
```

Above also it always prints false! But below is correct:

```
    int n = sizeof(int);

    // correct
    if(n > -1)
        cout << "true" << endl;
    else
        cout << "false" << endl;
```

Can anyone explain to me what happened? Thank you.

Comment: Isn’t it your homework to find the solution?

Comment: One question at a time please. If you have two questions, you should make two different posts.

Comment: @manni66: No. I never saw a homework as much short like this. Have you? lol

Comment: check this , you may get the answer =>
   unsigned int o = sizeof(int);
  if(o > -1)
      cout << "true" << endl;
  else
      cout << "false" << endl;

Comment: Consider this - what is the type of `x` when you write `auto x = sizeof(int);` ?  (hint - it's **not** an `int` ...  see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

Comment: @sam: So comparing an `unsigned int` with an `int` will produce `unsigned int`? Thus the unsigned value of `-1` is greater than the one of int (4)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof` evaluated to a constant of the `std::size_t` type. Which is an unsigned type large enough to contain the size of any object in your program. The keyword in the previous sentence is *unsigned*.

When you write `sizeof(int) > -1`, integral promotion rules in C++ dictate that both operands of the relational operator will be converted to the same type (the one large enough). This is the unsigned type. So `-1` is converted to some very large number. `SIZE_MAX` to be precise. The direct comparison will always evaluate to false.

But in the other case, you convert the `std::size_t` into an `int` via initialization (copy initialization to be precise, but it's beside the point). The value that the `sizeof` operator returns may in fact not fit in an `int`, in which case the value would not be preserved. But in your case it does fit (fundamental types are fairly small), and you get the expected result when comparing a positive `int` against `-1`.

Answer (score 5):

The result of [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) is a `std::size_t` value, and that's an unsigned integer type. In other words, it cannot be negative.

When you compare an unsigned integer number to a negative number like `-1` of equal or smaller bit length, then the negative number is interpreted as if its individual bits represented a huge positive number, so the comparison is false.

The `int n = sizeof(int);` case works as expected because the unsigned integer value returned by `sizeof` is first turned into an `int`, which is signed. You therefore end up with a comparison of two signed integers, which works in the expected arithmetic way.

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration.